# Get the solution to a system of nonlinear equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

I have the following system of nonlinear equations:

$$\begin{align}
\Delta t \omega x^{(\omega-2)/2} y^{\phi/2} &= r_L \tag{1}\label{eq1} \\
\Delta t \phi x^{\omega/2} y^{(\phi-2)/2} &= r_D \tag{2}\label{eq2}
\end{align}
$$

Where $\Delta t >0$ is a constant commom to both equations. I want to solve with respect to $x$ and $y$ without specifying any parameter ($\omega,\phi, r_L, r_D$). First I thought directly on the substitution method but it seemed not so easy.

So it cames on mind to divide $(1)$ by $(2)$ and isolate $y$ as a function of $x$ which leaves me to the following pair of equations

$$
\begin{align}
y = \frac{\phi r_L}{\omega r_D} x \tag{3}\label{eq3} \\
\Delta t \phi x^{\omega/2} y^{(\phi-2)/2} = r_D \tag{4}\label{eq4}
\end{align}
$$

Then the next step was inserting $(3)$ in $(4)$, which gave me

$$
x = \left(\frac{\omega}{r_L}\right)^{\frac{2-\phi}{\omega+\phi-2}} \left(\frac{r_D}{\phi}\right)^\frac{\phi}{\omega+\phi-2} \frac{1}{(\Delta t)^{\frac{2}{\omega+\phi-2}}}
$$

Finally, I isolated $x$ in $(3)$ and substituted in $(4)$ which gave me

$$
y = \left(\frac{r_D}{\phi}\right)^{\frac{2-\omega}{\omega+\phi-2}} \left(\frac{r_L}{\omega}\right)^\frac{\omega}{\omega+\phi-2} \frac{1}{(\Delta t)^{\frac{2}{\omega+\phi-2}}}
$$

*As important as the result: is my reasoning right?* And is there any software that would give me the solutions? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start simplifying the equations

$$\Delta t \omega x^{(\omega-2)/2} y^{\phi/2} = r_L\quad \implies \quad x^{(\omega-2)/2} y^{\phi/2}=\frac {r_L}{\Delta t \omega  }=a$$
$$\Delta t \phi x^{\omega/2} y^{(\phi-2)/2} = r_D \quad \implies \quad x^{\omega/2} y^{(\phi-2)/2}=\frac{r_D }{ \Delta t \phi}=b$$

Now, taking logarithms, let
$$X=\log(x) \qquad Y=\log(y)\qquad A=\log(a) \qquad B=\log(b)$$ which gives
$$\frac{\omega-2}2 X+\frac \phi 2 Y=A$$
$$\frac{\omega}2 X+\frac {\phi-2} 2 Y=B$$ which is more than simple.

When done, go back to the original variables.